# AP CS Practice - OOP

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance, interface

I am in AP CS and am trying to figure out if this works.

```
public interface Controller
public class Widget implements Controller
public class Thingy extends Widget

Controller myControl = new Thingy();
```

Assume that the interfaces/classes at the top are actually defined.  Does the forth line (`Controller myControl = new Thingy();`) work, or can you not create an object from an interface like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

In this case, you are instantiating an instance of `Thingy`, which is a concrete class. You have just declared it as type `Controller`. That just means anything using it can only access methods available in the interface `Controller` (unless they downcast, use reflection, etc). This is good practice because it allows you swap out the actual implementation of `myControl` and users of the object would not care.

Answer (score 1):

It is basics of polymorphism and inheritance - two terms that you should live and breath to fully understand OOP.

Consider this:

You have a Car interface, a SportsCar object which implements Car and a Porsche object which extends SportsCar.

SportsCar IS-A Car so you could say: `Car myCar = new SportsCar();`
Porsche IS-A SportsCar so you could say: `SportsCar myCar = new Porsche();`

By the same token, Porsche IS-A Car so you can definitely say:

```
Car myCar = new Porsche();
```

Bottom line is: A superclass (interface, abstract class or whatever) can hold references to its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an instance of the class *Thingy*, which implements *Controller*.  The *Controller* interface itself cannot be instantiated.